# How to call a macro from another macro in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheets, I have a macro that runs until an IFS statement wants to call another macro when true, but I get an error message instead.

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 48, 4).activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().If Range('B2').value = 10, Then Call Ten;
```

I expected the macro named Ten to run, and then return to run the final 2 rows of code (not shown).

Error message:

> Missing ; before statement. (line 16, file "macros")Dismiss

Comment: That last line is definitely not Javascript that's for sure.

Comment: Include your full code, including the function names etc for both this function and "Ten".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it will be something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange('B2');
  var value=rg.getValue();
  if(value==10){ 
    Ten();
  }
}
```