# How to create a macro that runs another macro?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I need to create a macro that runs hourly another exisitng one.
So at the end of every hour, the new macro should automatically run the existing one.

Comment: Plus you can create a timed based trigger that will run every hour (or what ever duration you want), even if the Spreadsheet is closed.  See this article https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Already answered -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/57207861/1595451

Answer (score 0):

#### Calling other functions

```
function func1() {
  const name = func2();
  Logger.log(name);
}

function func2() {
   return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Your Name","Enter Name",SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
}
```